# I can't figure out this error in my xml code

Tags: xml

This code is giving me this error and not sure what is causing it. I am a total xml beginner. error at line 1 char 159

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<center>
    <img border="0" src="lab12-1banner.jpg"></img>
    <h2>Indiana Oil Company - Refining and Distributing</h2>
</center>
<p>
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?><center><img border="0" src="lab12-1banner.jpg"></img><h2>Indiana Oil Company - Refining and Distributing</h2></center><p>

Answer (score 2):

An XML document may have only a single root element.  The unclosed opening `<p>` tag comes after the root element and is therefore the direct cause of your immediate error.  Delete it.

Consider also changing your encoding to UTF-8.  I see no evidence of you needing UTF-16.

Answer (score 1):

Try, breaking the XML into separate lines so you can see the correct error. Everything is on line 1 preventing a reasonable line number in the error message.

Also, are you sure you aren't writing HTML? I can't see all the lines in your example, but it appears to be HTML.

Finally, try using Internet Explorer to view your broken XML. It has clearer error messages than other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to have closed your `<p>` tag, and your XML document must have a tag surrounding all other elements. Other than that, the XML seems valid. Here is how you could make it valid:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
  <root>
  <center>
    <img border="0" src="lab12-1banner.jpg"></img>
    <h2>Indiana Oil Company - Refining and Distributing</h2>
  </center>
  <p>
  </p>
  </root>
```

Note the `root` tag surrounds all other elements (any other tag name would do - but it must exist), and a `</p>` is included after the opening `<p>`.